# How to solve a Volterra integral equation of the second kind

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis, integral-equations

I have the following equation
\begin{equation} 
F(\theta) + (c)^{\frac{1}{c}-1}\sqrt{\frac{c}{2\pi}}\int\limits_0^\theta
\frac{\theta^{\frac{1}{c}} - \tau^{\frac{1}{c}}}{(\theta -
\tau)^{3/2}}\exp{\left\{-\frac{(c)^{\frac{1}{c}-1}}{2}\frac{\left[\theta^{\frac{1}{c}}
- \tau^{\frac{1}{c}}\right]^2}{\theta -
\tau}\right\}}F(\tau)\,d\tau = \\-c k_0\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi
c\theta}}\exp{\left\{-\frac{\left[(c\theta)^{1/c} -
x_0\right]^2}{2c\theta}\right\}}.
\end{equation} 
Where $F$ is an unknown function and $c$, $k_0$ and $x_0$ are positive constants.

I am wondering, how to solve this analytically. I know that this can be solved numerically by the iteration method. I do not have much experience with the equations of this sort. Any help or guidance with this will be greatly appreciated, but I really want to understand how to solve it, not just obtain an answer.

Comment: When the integrand multipying $F(\tau)$ is a function of $\theta - \tau$ only (i.e. when the integral is a convolution) then such equations can be solved using the Laplace transform: 
$$F(\theta) = f(\theta) + \int_0^\theta g(\theta-\tau)F(\tau){\rm d}\tau \implies \hat{F}(s) = \frac{\hat{f}(s) }{1 -\hat{g}(s)}$$ 
which can be inverted to give us $F(\theta)$. Unfortunately this is only the case for your equation when $c=1$. I don't see a nice way to solve it when $c\not=1$ though. See for example [this](http://www.jirka.org/diffyqs/htmlver/diffyqsse40.html#x49-1810006.3.3) for more info.